# What is the best way to start for analysing DNA methylation TGCA datasets using R? I want to learn but I'm a novice

Tags: r, genetics

I am relatively new to programming and only have a basic knowledge base for R. I am keen on learning how to manipulate DNA methylation arrays for analysis related to Glioblastoma Multiforme. More specficially I will want to try and find patterns and trends associated with differences in survival linked to expression of mutations and how significant the relationship is with progression free and overall survival.

Any help would be MASSIVELY appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does the R library you want to use have a vignette?